# For loop and updater functions are not working in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object

I am trying to write a for loop in react in `componentDidMount`. It takes an array of words `reviewArray` and should return an object of each unique word and how many times each word is used. However it doesn't seem to loop at all, the logic inside the blocks works outside but when put into the loop it does nothing.

```
for (let i = 0; i < this.state.reviewsArray.length; i++) {
  let word = this.state.reviewsArray[i];
  if (!this.state.counts.hasOwnProperty(word)) {
    this.setState(prevState => {
      let counts = {...prevState.counts};
      counts.word = 1;
      return { counts };
    })
  } else {

    this.setState(prevState => {
      let counts = {...prevState.counts};
      counts.word += 1;
      return { counts };
    })
  }
}
```

`counts` returns an empty object defined in state.

Comment: `this.setState` runs asynchronously, that can be one reason. I would do the calculation first in the loop, then updating the state in one step at the end after the `for` loop.

Comment: How can I do the calculation without saving it thou? It adds +1 every time it finds an instance of a word so surely have to update the state of counts every time it does that

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

The main problem in your code is that you are doing setState multiple times inside the loop, that will cause to re-render the component, instead create a new object and only update the state at the end of the operation.

The other problem in your code is this line `counts.word`, since you are creating the properties dynamically, counts.words is not the word from the current array index, its only setting a value on `word` prop.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      reviewsArray: ["one", "two", "one"],
      counts: {}
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    let newState = Object.assign({}, this.state);

    for (let i = 0; i < newState.reviewsArray.length; i++) {
      let word = newState.reviewsArray[i];
      if (!newState.counts.hasOwnProperty(word)) {
        newState.counts[word] = 1;
      } else {
        newState.counts[word] += 1;
      }
    }

    this.setState(newState);
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state);
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
        <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: That's not worked unfortunately, the counts prop is still empty

Comment: Here is the full demo https://codesandbox.io/s/angry-brahmagupta-f842d?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark @AlexForrester

Comment: If you still cant make it work, could you post a full example of your code @AlexForrester, in the snippet above I get the correct values of counts

Comment: Thank you very much, I am doing all this in a component so will try it directly in Index.js. Can't see any other reason it wouldn't work

Comment: So your code works perfectly if I have the reviewsArray manually defined like in your example. My reviewsArray is populated from a fetched json file so thinking it might be trying to run the loop before the array is populated

Answer (score 0):

I'll be taking in a sample array to demonstrate the solution that I have. I think this is what you might be looking for.

```
let counts = {}; // initialise the object
const reviewArray = ["hey", "heyo", "hi", "wow", "cat", "dog", "mouse", "dog",
 "lion", "cat", "dog", "dog", "hey"]; // Suppose this is the reviewArray

reviewArray.map((item) => {
     if(counts.hasOwnProperty(item)){
      counts = {
        ...counts,
        [item]: counts[item] + 1, // Update the count if the key exists
      }
   } else {
      counts = {
        ...counts,
        [item]: 1        // Initialise if the key is encountered for the first time
      }
   }
})

this.setState({ counts }); //finally set the state with the updated object
```

If you feel i might have missed something please update. I think this should work fine.